# Get data from three tables

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have this code:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "select AName, FirstName, LastName, Address, CellPhone from ClientsT, AnimalsT where AppT.hasSchedule = @T and Month(AppT.ScheduleApp)= @MonthVacine and YEAR(AppT.ScheduleApp)= @YearVacine and AnimalT.AnimalID = AppT.AnimalID and AnimalsT.ClientID = ClientsT.ClientID";
command.CommandText = query;
command.Parameters.Add("@T", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = true;
command.Parameters.Add("@MonthVacine", OleDbType.Char).Value = month;
command.Parameters.Add("@YearVacine", OleDbType.Char).Value = year;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
listView2.Items.Clear();

while (reader.Read())
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["AName"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(reader["FirstName"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(reader["LastName"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(reader["Address"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(reader["CellPhone"].ToString());

    listView2.Items.Add(item);
}
reader.Close();

connection.Close();
```

When I run the program I get a message saying

> "no value given for one or more required parameters".

What I want, is away of searching in the AppT (appointments table) if there is an appointement scheduled (hasSchedule) and then check if matches the year and month that I provide (not interested in the day), after this I go to AnimalsT to get the AName (animal name) using AnimalID, and then I go to Clients to get their information FistName, LastName, Address, CellPhone using ClientID.

Comment: I do think in MS Access, you cannot use the `@Name` syntax but should use the `?` syntax.

Comment: have you tested the query outside of C# also are you familiar with using JOIN statements .. second question have you stepped through the code also have you thought about changing the Command.Parameters.Add method to use command.Parameters.AddWIthValue() method ..let the database resolve the data type for you.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with JOIN statements, infact this is the first time I am working with databases.

Answer (score 0):

The following code lines are setting the Value on a copy of the parameter you added:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@T", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = true;
command.Parameters.Add("@MonthVacine", OleDbType.Char).Value = month;
command.Parameters.Add("@YearVacine", OleDbType.Char).Value = year;
```

To fix this try this code instead:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@T", OleDbType.Boolean);
command.Parameters.Add("@MonthVacine", OleDbType.Char);
command.Parameters.Add("@YearVacine", OleDbType.Char);

command.Parameters["@T"].Value = true;
command.Parameters["@MonthVacine"].Value = month;
command.Parameters["@YearVacine"].Value = year;
```

Comment: I tried this metode, but now I have another error "An OleDbParameter with ParameterName is not contained by this OleDbParameterCollection".

Comment: Sorry actually appears that what you did originally should work according to MS